# Remove thin-like border when focusing a custom UITableCell

Tags: swift, tvos

### Question:

How do I remove the thin-like white border when focusing a custom UITableCell?

(In all honesty it has nothing to do with the border of a cell, I've tried modifying the color of the border to see)

### Description:

This seems to only occur when I leave the default focus style for the table cell via the storyboard, when I remove the default focus animation on the cell, the white borders do not appear (but then I have to implement my own custom animation..)

I've attempted to play around with different colors and tints but that didn't seem to work.

[image: border when focusing different cells]

*Above gif is showing the white border appearing when focusing a specific UITableCell*

**Screen shots of my UITableViewController Storyboard.**

[image: UITableViewCell]

*Image above is a screenshot of the attribute inspector for the UITableViewCell*

[image: Content View of my UITableViewCell]

*Image above is a screenshot of the attribute inspector for the Content View of my UITableViewCell*

[image: TableView]
*Image above is a screenshot of the attribute inspector for the UITableView*

Comment: did you try changing cell.layer.borderColor?

Comment: @ArpitDongre I did. The "border" of a cell and the effect I'm getting when focusing the cell are different. The border of a cell has a width smaller than the effect you see in the gif (it does have the same height). Also when pulling down or pulling up, the effect  can be seen from all 4 sides.

Comment: Can you show me the different color you have used in UITableViewCell, and focus style so I can simulate it?

Comment: @ArpitDongre I've added the images, but I think I won't keep them up for long. They're quite big... Let me know if that is what you wanted to see. Also the specific colors I've chosen for the background color of my table cell... they can be anything. This effect appears no matter what background color.

Comment: How did you change focus color, are you using a custom tableview cell?

Comment: @ArpitDongre yes I am, would you like to see the code for that as well?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130391/discussion-between-arpit-dongre-and-rugdealer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated:**

It's not border, but shadow. Now `UITableViewCellFocusStyle.default` is probably setting shadow to cell while focusing and when you scroll then even after hiding it, shadow is visible for a short period.

You can hide the shadow like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
     if let cell = context.nextFocusedView as? CustomTableViewCell {
        cell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0
        cell.layer.masksToBounds = true
     }
     //other configurations
}
```

**Note 1**: Shadow appears for a short period of time using above code. Use below code for no shadow.

Alternatively, you can use `UITableViewCellFocusStyle.custom` and give *default focus animation without shadow* manually like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUpdateFocusIn context: UITableViewFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
    let xScale = 1.008
    let yScale = 1.008
    if let cell = context.nextFocusedView as? CustomTableViewCell {
           coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: CGFloat(xScale), y: CGFloat(yScale))
            }, completion: nil)
    }

    if let previous = context.previouslyFocusedView as? CustomTableViewCell {
        coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
            previous.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity                
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    }
```

**Note:**

Try playing with **xScale** & **yScale** values for better animation.

Comment: Definitely an improvement ! Thank you ! However, the lines are still occasionally visible. Any ideas why?

Comment: Hi sorry for not getting back to you ! Actually, it did not add any visual difference (from my point of view). Would seem that the masksToBounds worked better. Maybe there is something I didn't quite understand. I've also noted that setting the cell.layer.backgroundColor does "hide" the unwanted shadow effect.

Answer (score 0):

Change your cell Focus style into **Custom**

[image: Focus Style Custom]

Comment: Yes, I know that it removes the white "border" but it also removes the default animation that I find is important, which is not what I want.